# OS power control utility written in C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, acpi

I am interested in making a simple command line utility ( in C ) to interact with the power management features of a linux OS ( using ACPI ).

I have a background in C programming and I hope with a little sweat and tears I can create this utility.

However! I am finding it very hard to start. I am finding it hard to find example code or anything other than technical documents on ACPI/its history.

If anyone has experience in this area I would greatly appreciate your advice! I am looking for sample code, how to's or really just any information for how to develop applications that interact with modern linux kernals and their power management features.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you plan on doing this in the kernel or from userspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the features that ACPI provides through sysfs. Specifically /sys/power from there you can read a lot of information as well as write to the "files" and have ACPI respond. There are other interfaces though if you plan on doing this for graphics cards or specific devices though.